# Why map type's kind is reported as 53 instead of 21?

Tags: go

show code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

// copy form src/runtime/type.go
type _type struct {
    size       uintptr
    ptrdata    uintptr // size of memory prefix holding all pointers
    hash       uint32
    tflag      tflag
    align      uint8
    fieldAlign uint8
    kind       uint8
    equal      func(unsafe.Pointer, unsafe.Pointer) bool
    gcdata     *byte
    str        nameOff
    ptrToThis  typeOff
}
type tflag uint8
type nameOff int32
type typeOff int32

// copy form src/runtime/runtime2.go
type eface struct {
    _type *maptype
    data  unsafe.Pointer
}

// copy form src/runtime/type.go
type maptype struct {
    typ    _type
    key    *_type
    elem   *_type
    bucket *_type // internal type representing a hash bucket
    // function for hashing keys (ptr to key, seed) -> hash
    hasher     func(unsafe.Pointer, uintptr) uintptr
    keysize    uint8  // size of key slot
    elemsize   uint8  // size of elem slot
    bucketsize uint16 // size of bucket
    flags      uint32
}

func main() {
    var t interface{} = map[int]int{1: 1}

    p := (*eface)(unsafe.Pointer(&t))

    fmt.Println(p._type.typ.kind) // 53
}
```

print 53,

but you can find in src/runtime/typekind.go

```golang
const (
    kindBool = 1 + iota
    kindInt
    kindInt8
    kindInt16
    kindInt32
    kindInt64
    kindUint
    kindUint8
    kindUint16
    kindUint32
    kindUint64
    kindUintptr
    kindFloat32
    kindFloat64
    kindComplex64
    kindComplex128
    kindArray
    kindChan
    kindFunc
    kindInterface
    kindMap // 21
    kindPtr
    kindSlice
    kindString
    kindStruct
    kindUnsafePointer

    kindDirectIface = 1 << 5
    kindGCProg      = 1 << 6
    kindMask        = (1 << 5) - 1
)
```

the map type is const 21. Similarly, chan is 50 instead of kindChan(18). Why?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [src/runtime/typekind.go](https://go.dev/src/runtime/typekind.go), there is a function to check if the value is stored directly in an interface value, which applies to your case, as you are creating `t` of `interface{}` but storing a map type to it.

```golang
// isDirectIface reports whether t is stored directly in an interface value.
func isDirectIface(t *_type) bool {
    return t.kind&kindDirectIface != 0
}
```

When using that on your value of `p` as `isDirectIface(&p._type.typ)` it returns `true`, because of the underlying bit value corresponding to interface type is set (`kindDirectIface = 1 << 5`, 32)

So in effect, the value 53 represents (decimal 21+32) a map type 21 (`kindMap`) stored as an interface type 32 (`kindDirectIface`)